# How to grep both header and pattern with grep

Tags: linux, bash

I need to grep both header and also particular pattern only using grep,

eg

for command "ps"
output

```
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
10280 pts/16   00:00:00 ps
32463 pts/16   00:00:00 bash
```

how can i grep both header and pattern like 32463 so output should be

```
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
32463 pts/16   00:00:00 bash
```

And One thing is that solution should be general that means it should be applicable to all commands that have headers

Comment: By "grep header" do you mean search the header for the same phrase (trivial) or actually just print the header every time? Or search the header for a different phrase?

Answer (score 4):

Like this:

```
ps | ( read -r head; printf '%s\n' "$head"; grep bash )
```

This generalizes to other commands, such as

```
( read -r head; printf '%s\n' "$head"; sort -k4n ) <input.csv >input-sorted-4n.csv
```

You could encapsulate this into a script called `keepheader`:

```
#!/bin/sh
read -r head
printf '%s\n' "$head"
exec "$@"
```

Use like

```
ps | keepheader grep bash
keepheader sort -k4n <input.csv >input-sorted-4n.csv
```

or maybe even

```
keepheader keepheader grep foo <<HERE
Header with underlines
------ ---- ----------
Cat    food Whiskas
Mouse  bait Cheese
HERE
```

(Actually maybe make the script accept an optiinal numeric parameter to specify how many header lines to keep; I leave this as an exercise for the reader.)

Comment: your solution applicable to lot of commands but for "cat" it is not working. It only printing header only ....

Comment: @user2572969 It also does not work for `ps`, only gives the head line.

Comment: Interesting. I just learned that `read(1)` does not use buffered input, so the updated answer really works. Although I think the solution is too complex.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
ps | head -1; ps | grep bash
```

Comment: Those two launches of `ps` may give different outputs.

Comment: The first launch will just yield the header, the second will give you the desired data. probably you should give him +1 again.

Comment: Probably you can try `ps -ef|{ head -1; grep bash; }`

Answer (score 2):

I suggest `sed`:

```
sed -n "1p;/$pattern/p"
```

Answer (score 1):

1. > how can i grep both header and pattern

   You could try this

   ```
   ps | grep -e 'PID\|32463'
   ```
2. > solution should be general that means it should be applicable to all commands that have headers

   This requirement is almost impossible to satisfy by `grep`, because different commands have different headers, it is impossible to assign a regular expression to match all of them.

   But you could use the following command to achieve your goal:

   ```
   command | perl -e 'while(<STDIN>) { print if $. == 1 or m/$ARGV[0]/ }' pattern
   ```

   If it is too cumbersome for daily use, you can put it in a custom script, such as `my-grep`, and put that script in your `$PATH`, then you can use that script like a normal command:

   ```
   command | my-grep pattern
   ```

Answer (score 0):

With out using grep you can get this output for `ps` option

```
  $ps -p 32463

     -p  Select by PID.
         This selects the processes whose process ID numbers appear in pidlist. Identical to p and --pid.
```